How to know the hidden meanings in Surah Al-Fatiha for curing illness?
I've read a hadith(authentic) where a companion healed another person by reciting Fatiha. It's also recited among the Salaf for healing purposes.
But one needs to know the subtle meanings of this surah & what it contains of to properly avail its healing ability(obv all healing comes from Allah SWT, everything else just a medium). Source: Zad Al-Ma`ad  4/318
So, how do I come to know these subtle meanings & insights from the Surah Al-Fatiha?
